# iOS alternative PDF Renderer

Tags: ios, pdf, quartz-core, mupdf

I am looking for a good alternative PDF Renderer.

Currently I am using Quartz Core for PDF rendering, which is great and pretty fast, but I find it still slow compared to other iOS Apps (GoodReader has an own renderer or has adapted some kind of alternative renderer and is not disclosing any information about it).

I am wondering if there are some good open source or payd PDF Renderers for iOS that I could try out.

I tried muPDF, but it does not support iOS and it would take a lot of time to make it compatible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe GoodReader has a custom render engine. It's all a matter of caching and using the idle times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this viewer: http://www.vfr.org/2011/06/pdf-reader-viewer-v1-2-1/

Comment: Thanks! I also integrated and tried fastPDFKit's (http://mobfarm.eu/fastpdfkit) renderer and it helped (the rendering is now faster by about 200ms, roughly). Problem is that it is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

MuPDF compiles and runs just fine on iOS.

All you need to do is create an Xcode project for it, drop in the MuPDF, thirdparty and generated data file sources and compile. I used to have an iOS demo app for testing on the platform, but I haven't been paying the Apple developer tax so it's not up to date.

Comment: Good Luck with using GPL code in your iOS app. Besides that you have to open source your whole app, if *any* contributor complains against Apple, your app will be deleted. Just check VLC for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The best open source project I've found yet for iOS (iPhone/iPad) is http://www.vfr.org/ ( source code available here : https://github.com/vfr/Reader ).
It has a very nice design and some nice features !